# How do I preserve ASCII value in string?

Tags: c#, .net

How do I get have the string save ascii value in it?

Let's say I have this script.

```
string stringValue = "";

for(var x = 1; x < 32; x++)
{
    stringValue += x.ToString();
}

byte[] byteValues = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringValue);
```

In byte, you get 49, 50, 51, 52, etc. The question is how to save it to string like "49505152".  (Looks like 49 50 51 52 combined in string).

Thanks.

Comment: Why on earth would you *want* "49505152" etc? Can you give us more context as to what you're really trying to achieve?

Comment: PHP programmer from a company use "$foo = chr(x)" to build encryption key.  Don't ask me why.

Comment: This *really* feels like an XY problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @fletchsod Bad security *should* prompt you to ask "why?".

Comment: I am curious to see the production code :)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use `string.Concat`

```
var result = string.Concat(byteValues);
```

You can also re-write your loop using the same method:

```
string stringValue = string.Concat(Enumerable.Range(1, 31));
```

Comment: (Not voting) Any reason why string.Concat instead of string.Join?

Comment: because there is no need for a delimiter

Comment: @downvoters, is this answer incorrect or are you just downvoting because you don't like the question ?

Comment: It is  not an answer.

Comment: The first line should be correct. The second line produces the numbers 1-31 stuck together, which doesn't use Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes.